# Neighbourhood definition of topological structure: Why does every neighbourhood of x contain an open set containing x

Tags: general-topology

Given the neighbourhood axiomatization of topological structure, how do you prove that every neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ contains an open set $U$ where $x \in U$?

In more detail:

Consider the Axioms for neighbourhoods from Section 2.1 of Ronald Brown's textbook *Topology and Groupoids*

The textbook is available for free online on Ronald Brown's website: http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html.

The direct link to the pdf is: https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/topgrpds-e.pdf.

The definition is given verbatim as

> Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{N}$ a function assigning to each $x$ in $X$ a non-empty set $\mathcal{N(x)}$ of subsets of $X$. The elements of $\mathcal{N(x)}$ will be called *neighbourhoods of* $x$ *with respect to* $\mathcal N$ (or, simply, *neighbourhoods of* $x$). The function $\mathcal N$ is called a *neighbourhood topology* if Axioms **N1-N4** below are satisfied; and then $X$ with $\mathcal N$ is called a *topological space*.
> The following axioms must hold for each $x$ in $X$.
> **N1** *If* $N$ *is a neighbourhood of* $x$*, then* $x\in N$.
> **N2** *If* $N$ *is a subset of* $X$ *containing a neighbourhood of* $x$*, then* $N$ *is a neighbourhood of* $x$.
> **N3** *The intersection of two neighbourhoods of* $x$ is again a neighbourhood of $x$.
> **N4** *Any neighbourhood* *N* of $x$ contains a neighbourhood *M* of *x* such that $N$ is a neighbourhood of each point of *M*.

I think I have seen definitions where the fourth axiom above is stated as:

> **N4***: *Any neighbourhood* *N* of $x$ contains a neighbourhood *M* of *x* such that $M$ is a neighbourhood of each element in itself.

Or in other words, that any neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ contains an open set $M$ containing $x$ (where the definition of an open set in terms of neighbourhoods is a set $U$ which is a neighbourhood of all points in $U$). Now, I see that **N1-N3+N4*** implies **N1-N4** because of **N2**. My question is how to prove **N4*** from **N1-N4**.

Even if I am misremembering and **N4*** is not used anywhere, I think it is still true because of the equivalent definition of a topological space in terms of open sets. In that approach, one recovers the neighbourhoods by defining that a set $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ if it contains an open set $U$ and $x \in U$.

I also read through some of Nicolas Bourbaki's text *Elements of Mathematics General Topology* and found the same set of axioms as **N1-N4** (in Chapter 1 *Topological structures* in the subsection on Neighbourhoods). More specifically:

In that text, the definition of topological structure is presented in terms of open sets.

The text then moves on to define neighbourhoods

> Definition 4. *Let* $X$ *be a topological space and* $A$ *any subset of* $X$*. A neighbourhood of* $A$ *is any subset of* $X$ *which contains an open set containing* $A$*. The neighbourhoods of a subset* $\{x\}$ *consisting of a single point are also called neighbourhoods of the point* $x$*.*

It then states

> Proposition 1: *A set is a neighbourhood of each of its points if and only if it is open.*

After this, the properties of neighbourhoods of $x$ are listed as $\mathbf{V_I}$**-**$\mathbf{V_{IV}}$. The text says

> Let us denote by $\mathcal{B(x)}$ the set of all neighbourhoods of $x$. The sets $\mathcal{B(x)}$ have the following properties:
> ($\mathbf{V_I}$) *Every subset of* $X$ *which contains a set belonging to* $\mathcal{B(x)}$ *itself belongs to* $\mathcal{B(x)}$.
> ($\mathbf{V_{II}}$) *Every finite intersection of sets of* $\mathcal{B(x)}$ *belongs to* $\mathcal{B(x)}$.
> ($\mathbf{V_{III}}$) *The element* $x$ *is in every set of* $\mathcal{B(x)}$.
> ($\mathbf{V_{IV}}$) *If* $V$ *belongs to* $\mathcal{B(x)}$*, then there is a set* $W$ *belonging to* $\mathcal{B(x)}$ *such that, for each* $y\in W$*,* $V$ *belongs to* $\mathcal{B(y)}$

However, the text then states that:

> By Proposition 1, we may take $W$ to be any open set which contains $x$ and is contained in $V$.

But I do not see how one can take $W$ this way.

I have thought about this and searched for an answer but haven't had any luck. Am I missing something trivial? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a good wikipedia article on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $N\subset X,$ let us prove that the subset
$$O:=\{x\in X\mid N\in\mathcal N(x)\}$$
satisfies
$$\forall a\in O\quad O\in\mathcal N(a).$$
Let $a\in O,$ i.e. $N\in\mathcal N(a).$ By N4, there exists $M\in\mathcal N(a)$ such that $\forall x\in M\quad N\in\mathcal N(x),$ i.e. such that $M\subset O.$
By N2, $O\in\mathcal N(a).$